# Setting ModelBuilder to ignore error and continue?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, clip

I am running a couple of models to firstly, reproject a directory of raster images and secondly to clip them to a polygon boundary.  When running the clip the model exits if a raster falls just outside the clip polygon.

Is there a way that I can change a setting to have ModelBuilder note the error and move on without quitting?

I do not understand python so please, no suggestions about how it could solve the problem.  If there is no setting I can change I will try other approaches.

Comment: What if you set the processing extent (in the Environment settings) of the Clip tool to the extent of the boundary? I'm wondering if that would return essentially empty rasters which you could check for later.

Comment: Another idea is If/Then branching, but I'm not sure of a simple way to check if they overlap.. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm